# Perda de dados ao girar tela

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um APP Android, nele você digita alguns valores nos EditText. Mas quando vc vira o telefone para mudar a orientação os dados dos EditText são perdidos. Como resolvo?

Comment: Oi Leandro. Poste seu código para que possamos ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Use os métodos put para guardar os valores em onSaveInstanceState:

```java
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle extra) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(extra);
  extra.putString("text", "your text here");
}
```

E restaure em onCreate:

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle extra) {
  if (extra != null) {
    String value = extra.getString("text");
  }
}
```

Por ultimo, remova do manifest `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`